# mail() php doesn't send in html format

Tags: php, html, email

I tried questions already answered over here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447072/not-able-to-send-html-in-mail-function-via-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722979/php-mail-function-not-sending-in-html-format), and others...), but nothing get worked... i have this function to send an email:

```
function send_email($para, $assunto, $msg){
    $to      = $para;
    $subject = $assunto;

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= str_replace("\\r\\n","<br/>",$msg);
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    $headers = 'From: email@realemail.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: email@realemail.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

    return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

And i'm calling this with something like that:

```
$var = "<p><strong>...blablabla...</strong></p>";

send_email("email@email", "lalala", $var);
```

I can send the email, but it ins't html formatted (and it contains the html tags, except for `HTML` and `BODY`). What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**:
The email is displayed like this (exactly the same content sent, except for `HTML` and `BODY` TAG):

```
BEGIN
<p><strong>...blablabla</strong></p>
END
```

When i get the full email (like [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454) tutorial), shows up that the email was sent with TAGS html, body, etc...
A piece of the email:

```
Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
...
To: myemail@gmail.com
Subject: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
From: sender@email.com
Reply-To: sender@email.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.6.19
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
MIME-Version: 1.0
...
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 15:51:48 -0200
...
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - svr1.ravehost.com.br
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [99 497] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - svr1.ravehost.com.br

<html><body>...blablabla...</body></html>
```

Comment: could you eventually also copy/paste here the resulting e-mail message with headers and all?

Comment: See the edit1 @Dragos.

Comment: Other then the headers being in incorrect order your code looks fine. Maybe there is a problem on the client side, which mail client are you using?

Comment: Try changing `Content-type` to `Content-Type` (upper case the T).

Comment: @PMateus E-mail, proper MIME encoding, and multi-part messages are an utter nightmare and you would be crazy to have to figure out all the quirks yourself.  :-)  Use an existing mail library that does this for you, such as PHPMailer or similar.

Comment: I tried this on my local PHP/windows env. and see the headers/body as: `Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 14:22:01 -0800
Subject: lalala
To: <xyz@mydomain.com>
From: <xyz@mydomain.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.6.10
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
MIME-Version: 1.0 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></head>
<body><p><strong>Prepared do an dissuade be....&nbsp;</strong></p><p><s>Society excited by cottage private an it esteems. ...&nbsp;</s></p><p><em>Whole every miles as tiled at seven or. .&nbsp;</em></p></body></html>`

Comment: @Ross still not working...

Comment: @Brad, yeah... i don't wanna use this lib, but until now i couldn't make it run properly, so i'm gonna try.

Comment: Try changing the order of the headers. First MIME-Version and Content-type and only after that the From, To, Reply-To and so on

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is an exact solution, but this solved html email problems I was having with Microsoft Outlook.

Replace all of the `\r\n` in the headers with `PHP_EOL`. I did this when I was having issues with sending html emails in PHP, and it seemed to solve my particular problems.

Comment: `PHP_EOL` changes its value depending on the platform you're using.  If you run PHP on Windows, you'll get `\r\n`.  If you run it on Linux, you'll get `\n`.